# Unable to load static files on django with gunicorn ,nginx on Google compute engine

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am trying to deploy a sample app on google compute engine and have a centos7 instance setup. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7).

Everything is working fine but the static files are not loading. I have used the setting :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

and ran `collectstatic` command. The static file directory is created in the project and have all the static files.

Here is my **nginx.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name My_External_IP ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/user/myproject/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample error from nginx **error.log**:

```
2015/06/29 06:49:49 [error] 3566#0: *3 open() "/home/user/myproject/static/admin/css/login.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: <<MY_IP>>
, server: <<SERVER_IP>>, request: "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1", host: "<<SERVER_IP>>", referrer: "http://<<SERVER_IP>>/admin/login/?next=/admin/"
```

Please suggest what to do.

Edit:
I am also getting this message when I run systemctl status nginx:

```
Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Seems like your nginx user doesn't have permissions to that directory.

Comment: Looks like a (13: Permission denied) for nginx in that folder. Check nginx has the right permissions and selinux is not blocking it (selinux can make some files unreadable for nginx although nginx has permissions)

Comment: I have used these commands to setup nginx permissions:
sudo usermod -a -G user nginx
chmod 710 /home/user